# Singstar disc keeps spinning

Tags: ps2, singstar

I am currently using Singstar party for the first time, and am trying to use the change disc feature to swap to Singstar Legends. When I open the tray, however, the disc keeps spinning at full speed. Forcing the disc switch by stopping it with my finger just causes the game to crash with a loud buzzing.

What can I do to use this feature? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the release identifiers? They can be found in the box (side of the case) or the disc (under the PlayStation logo). It should look something like SCES-00000.

Comment: @Lemon SCES-52826 For Party, SCES-54191 for Legends. Together with 80s (SCES-53603) no combination of master disc and loaded disc works; they all keep spinning as described.

Comment: What Model PS2 are you using? Original, or Slim? What is the serial number of your PS2?

Comment: @DontCopyThatFloppy Slim. Serial FC4328375